# Creating connection pool in psycopg2 using connection string

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I created a connection object by passing a connection string to psycopg2.connect and it works fine.

All the settings are saved in a dictionary and called this way:

```py
import psycopg2

connection_string = configs['database']['type'] + "://" + configs['database']['user'] + ":" + configs['database']['pass'] + "@" + configs['database']['server'] + '/' + configs['database']['db']
connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
```

But I want to create a simple connection pool and passing the same setting generate an error

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import pool

connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1,100,
                                                     user=configs['database']['user'],
                                                     password=configs['database']['pass'],
                                                     host=configs['database']['type'] + "://" + configs['database']['server'],
                                                     port=5432,
                                                     database=configs['database']['db'])
```

I get this error message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "xxxxx.xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:5432" to address: Unknown host
```

I tried different values for host such as adding "postgresql://" at the beginning of the host name but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like configs['database']['server'] has a ":5432" tacked onto the end.  You will either need to change your config to remove it, or parse that data entry into two parts, the real server, and the port number.